# slideshow images are occupying more space in the site

Tags: admin, theme, image, gallery

please visit this link :

this is ma_aries magento theme by Plaza themes

check the home page- slideshow images. Slideshow images are occupying more size.

I resized the images and uploaded. than also it's not occupying less size.

there is no option in admin panel to resize the image sizes.

please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Edit this CSS file
  `http://theme8.newtrendzonline.com/ma_aries_quickstart_1.8.0.0/skin/frontend/default/ma_aries_man/magentothem/css/ma.banner7.css`
- `Go to Line no. 42`
- Make cahanges like following:

> .ma-banner7-container .flexslider {
>           margin: 0 0 20px;
>           **max-height: 500px;**
>           position: relative;
>       }

- here I have added only max-height property as 500px, you can change it as per your need

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, i will change and let you know soon....

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your help, it's worked....